# How to open an issue on Github after a Jenkins build fail

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, github-api

We have a Jenkins instance which runs a bunch of compilation and integration jobs. They are all triggered by pull requests or commits to github repositories.  We are  using the Jenkins Github plugin for this.

I would like an issue to be opened on the respective repositories, by jenkins, if the build fails.

The only way I can think of doing this at the moment is to use the Github API via a curl request. Is there a "better" way of doing this ?

(reposted from ServerFault).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since nobody else wants to take a crack, here's my solution.

I added a conditional post-build task to execute a shell. The shell is just a post to the Github API to create the new issue.